# Objects in holdout collection showing in render when their alpha value in Principled BSDF is not 1 or 0

Tags: rendering, transparency

i have a collection with holdout on it. Couple objects inside of that use alpha values on Principled BSDF and i’ve noticed that when the value isn’t exactly 1 or 0, it will show up on the render as half transparent object. Is this the expected behavior or can i do anything to competely cutout these objects still? Preferably by keeping the alpha values as they are.

see the issue here: https://imgur.com/a/0hjccml

Comment: did you check transparent in film options? if yes, pls provide blend file. thx.

Comment: I had to strip the file to bare minimum, but you can see the issue here https://we.tl/t-d9U9Ot0saa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at it closely, there is a clear correlation between the *Alpha* value and the appearance of the objects. It is not that they only show up semi-transparent when they are not 0 or 1, but there is a difference between 0 and 1 as well: when the *Alpha* is 1, the objects are holdouts - i.e., their shape is "cut out" of the image and there is transparency behind them, no matter if you have set *Film* > *Transparent* or not, even if there is an HDRI in the background, the holdout objects are cut out and there is transparency. They do appear in reflections and throw shadows though.

But that is not what happens if the *Alpha* is set 0. In this case, the objects are simply transparent, i.e. they are invisible in the scene and also do not appear in reflections or throw shadows or anything. However they do not cut out everything in their place.

The *Holdout* setting for a collection is like adding a *Holdout* shader node to all materials of the object. The *Alpha* channel in the *Principled BSDF* is like using a normal opaque shader and combining it with a *Transparent BSDF* via *Mix Shader* node, and the mix factor is the *Alpha* value.

Now the *Alpha* value effects the collection *Holdout* in a way as if the objects had a material with a *Holdout* nand a *Transparent* node mixed together, and the *Alpha* value controls how much the object is transparent or holdout.

As you might have noticed, setting *Alpha* for example to 0.5, the object becomes semi-transparent - but instead of showing half transparency and half the *Principled BSDF*, it shows half holdout. So the *Holdout* replaces the opaque part of the *Principled BSDF*.

### Visual examples:

Let's say I have this scene. The three cubes are together in a collection, they all are  opaque with an *Alpha* value of 1 in their *Principled BSDF* and there is an HDRI in the background.

[image: basic scene]

Now I enable *Holdout* for the collection of the cubes. Wherever they are in front of something, they mask out the image and show transparency. But they are still "visible" to the other objects in the scene, they are in the reflections and throw shadows.

[image: normal holdout]

If you now set all *Alpha* values on the cubes to 0, this would be like when you mix them with a *Transparent BSDF* and set the mix to 100% transparent. They are invisible to the camera and the scene objects, no reflections, no shadows. But also no masking. This is the same as if you had no *Holdout* enabled - because the *Holdout* simply spoken replaces the opaque part of the shader - since this is like 100% transparent, there is no opacity to be replaced with a holdout.

[image: full transparency]

If I now set the *Alpha* to a value between 0 and 1 you can see, the cubes are partly transparent and show what is behind them (like normal transparency) and partly show a transparent background (like a normal holdout). Notice that the semi-transparent do not show their color (only in the reflections).

[image: semi-transparent holdout]

If the cubes would not be affected by the holdout and simply use their *Principled BSDF* settings with partial transparency, it would look like that, the cubes showing their colors although being partly see-through.

[image: normal transparency]

### Possible workaround

A slightly tedious workaround (depending on how many semi-transparent objects you have in the *Holdout* collection) would be to mask those objects with a *Cryptomatte* node in the *Compositor*. Let's re-use the example scene from before. This time, two cubes are opaque and therefore masked out completely like they are supposed to be, but the one on the right has an *Alpha* value < 1 and is just partly masking the image:

[image: partly masked cube]

What you can do now is go to the *View Layer Properties* tab and under *Passes* enable *Cryptomatte* > *Object*.

[image: enable cryptomatte]

This allows you to use a *Cryptomatte* node - not *Cryptomatte (Legacy)*! - in the *Compositor* like this: you need to have *Backdrop* enabled and use a *Viewer* node. With the rendered image in the background, click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button next to the *Matte ID* field in the *Cryptomatte* node. This enables an eyedropper tool with which you can click on the semi-transparent cube to select it. If you now plug the *Pick* output into the *Viewer* node, you can see that the selected cube is masked.

[image: cube mask]

Of course what you want for the alpha of the cube is the exact opposite, so you can use an *Invert Color* node to invert the mask. If you now plug this mask and the *Alpha* output of the *Render Layers* node into a *Math* node set to *Minimum*, the semi-transparent grey value of the original alpha will be replaced with the black from the inverted *Cryptomatte*. The result can be plugged into a *Set Alpha* node and replace the original alpha channel.

[image: set new alpha]

The tedious part of this process is, the *Cryptomatte* node does not work with collections, so if you have a lot of semi-transparent objects in the *Holdout* collection, you have to select them all separately one by one. I should also mention, the *Cryptomatte* node does not work with volumetric materials (neither does *Holdout*).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What would be the solution? https://imgur.com/a/0hjccml

Comment: @Esvee I just added visual examples to explain the different behaviours. Well, there is no solution really. The materials on holdout objects cannot have transparency to be fully masking. Basically the holdout creates an alpha mask for the image, setting all to black where the holdout objects are. The _Alpha_ channel sets the alpha mask in places where the according material is to the value it has. So both are manipulating the alpha, and unfortunately there is no "use maximum", "use minimum" or anything to tell Blender which has more priority. No separate _Render Pass_ for the holdout either.

Comment: I guess this would be something one could place as a feature request, to either make the _Holdout_ collection setting override any alpha values on objects or to have a separate _Holdout_ pass that could be used in the _Compositor_.

Comment: Or... there is a way to accomplish a masking for the holdout objects with _Cryptomatte_. This is not the best solution because it can be tedious if you have many semi-transparent objects in this collection, but I can add it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing reply with the examples. I guess In this case i will set the alpha manually on all objects to 1 for the cutout shots, i have about 20 angles to render, i will just put cameras on timeline with markers and render as animation and then set the values back. Probably the quickest way?

Comment: @Esvee I've added the _Cryptomatte_ workaround to my answer. By the way, regarding your username: when you render with _EEVEE_, the _Alpha_ setting is no problem. _EEVEE_ ignores the alpha value when you have set the collection to _Holdout_.